# Issue reading textfiles in Python without error

Tags: python

I've got an issue with Python 2.7.8 on Mac OS 10.10.1 an simply reading a textfile and I have no idea what is causing the problem. I used writing and reading to textfiles in this way several times before without any problems.

I successful write some lines to a textfile. After a short time of waiting I try to read that file again and print out each line. But there is neither a line printed nor raised an exception.

Any ideas what went wrong here?

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time

# Testdatei erstellen

write_fobj = open("testtxt.txt", "w")
write_fobj.write ("testzeile 1" + "\n")
write_fobj.write ("testzeile 2" + "\n")
write_fobj.write ("testzeile 3" + "\n")
write_fobj.close

time.sleep(2)

# Testdatei laden

try:
    read_fobj = open("testtxt.txt", "r")
    for line in read_fobj:
        print (line)
    read_fobj.close()

except: 
    import traceback
    print traceback.format_exc()
```

Comment: You forgot to _call_ `.close`.

Comment: @user3645735 To be more clear you forgot the "()" the first time you open the file. The right way to close is .close()

Answer (score 0):

File is not closed.

Change `write_fobj.close` statement to `write_fobj.close()`